# Mongoose: TypeError: 'mongooseSchemahere' is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following mongoose Schema setup in models/user.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    loginId: String,
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    eMail: String,
    password: String,
    active: Boolean

});

module.exports = userSchema;
```

In my main app.js I have the following code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url,  {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  },function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("db");
  dbo.collection("db").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    db.close();
  });
}); 

let userSchema = require('./models/user.js');
// Get single user
app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res) {
  userSchema.findById(req.params.id, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error)
    } else {
      res.json(data)
    }
  })
})
```

I get the error which is in the title (just replace mongooseSchemahere with userSchema). What did I do wrong? I tried putting the userSchema declaration in different places, it did not help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use mongoose.connect to work with mongoose models.

Make these changes:

1-)  Create the user model like this and export:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  loginId: String,
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  eMail: String,
  password: String,
  active: Boolean
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

2-) Change your App.js to connect your db with mongoose.connect:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("./models/user");
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.json());

mongoose
  .connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
    });
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Now you can create a user like this:

```
app.post("/user", function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("Req body:", req.body);
  User.create(req.body)
    .then(result => {
      console.log({ result });
      res.send(result);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send("something went wrong");
    });
});
```

To retrieve the user by _id:

```
app.get("/user/:id", function(req, res, next) {
  User.findById(req.params.id, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    } else {
      res.json(data);
    }
  });
});
```

To retrieve a user by firstname: (if you want to find all users by firstname change findOne to find.):

```
app.get("/user/firstname/:firstname", function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.params.firstname);
  User.findOne({ firstname: req.params.firstname }, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    } else {
      res.json(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Now I get `FATAL: Uncaught exception.
ReferenceError: next is not defined` :/

Comment: @Munchkin can you try with the updated answer? I  updated the App.js. next was  also missing in your code

Comment: I get `CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "test" at path "_id" for model "User"` now

Comment: @Munchkin  ObjectId's automatically generated by mongodb.  Do you try to post user with _id value test_ If so it is wrong, don't set _id any value.

Comment: I did not set any _id value but somewhy it asks for it. AFAIK _id is automatically generated by MongoDB

Comment: @Munchkin are you trying to get users or post user?

Comment: I am trying to get user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203090/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-munchkin).

Answer (score 1):

You need to export the model and not the schema.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    loginId: String,
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    eMail: String,
    password: String,
    active: Boolean

});

module.exports =  mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

Now you can do things like:

```
let User = require('./models/user.js');
// Get single user
app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res) {
  User.findById(req.params.id, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error)
    } else {
      res.json(data)
    }
  })
})
```